# CS0019 C# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Tags: c#, operators

I have an or operator (||) with an integer but for some reason it gives me an error. The integer is location. i want to track the players location, so i can control all the actions in one chunk of code. The lines that look like `if (location == (1 || 2 || 3)` give me the error.

```
Actions:
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.Write("What should i do? ");
            string move = Console.ReadLine();
            if (move.Contains("north"))
            {
                if (location == (1 || 2 || 3))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is a cliff here I cant climb up!");
                }
            }
            else if (move.Contains("east"))
            {
                if (location == (3 || 6 || 9))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is a cliff here I cant climb up!");
                }
            }
            else if (move.Contains("south"))
            {
                if (location == (7 || 8 || 9))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is a cliff here I cant climb up!");
                }
            }
            else if (move.Contains("west"))
            {
                if (location == (1 || 2 || 3))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is a cliff here I cant climb up!");
                }
            }
            else if (move.Contains("grab"))
            {
                if (location == (6))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I don't have time for apples!");
                }
                else if (location == (8))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("It's locked!");
                }
                else if (location == (1 ||2 || 4 || 5 || 7 || 9))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is nothing to grab!");
                }
                else if (location == (3))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I grabbed the key.");
                    bool key = true;
                }
            }
            else if (move.Contains("use"))
            {

            }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: And `if (location == (6))` can become just `if (location == 6)`

Comment: be sure to check language documentation before posting a question. this is a trivial sintax error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
if(location == 1 || location ==  2 || location ==  3)
```

Answer (score 3):

I get the impression that you should familiarize yourself a little more with the fact that programming language is not the same as natural language.

In natural language you would say "if that number is 1 or 2 or 3, do something" and everybody will understand you.

On the other hand programming languages are mostly built on logic and arithmethics. It is much easier for a machine (the compiler) to understand what you want, if it can apply a limited set of rules to what you write.

If it has more rules for that, it **might** give you the additional option to write "location == (1 || 2 || 3)" and translate it to what the other answers have told you to write instead.

The drawback of such an approach is, that this additional option is very likely to introduce what you finally probably would call ambiguous or contradictory, where you write something else and the compiler will translate it into something that you would have never expected.

The rules in this case are basically very clear:

- 1, 2, 3 are expressions (very trivial ones)
- in x||y the || is an operator which takes two expressions/operands (one on the left, x, and one on the right, y) to form another expression (recursively so to speak)
- || expects its operands **to evaluate (that means: calculate) to true or false** (numbers like 1,2,3 don't really fit there, or would you say that 3 is true or false; side note: some programming languages will even accept numbers where truth is expected) and will evaluate to true or false as well
- x==y is an operator that takes two expressions (which can be numeric or truth values) and it finally evaluates to true or false
- if (x) y is a statement that accepts this truth expression in brackets in order to execute what's behind the brackets, or not.

So to summarize: the compile error shows you that you have not yet understood, how the language constructs are interpreted by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write conditions this way, instead use:

```
if (location == 7 || location == 8 || location == 9 )
```

or you can use a `switch` statement instead, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can't compare a variable agains't multiple values. Your code should be like this:

```
if (location == 1 || location == 2 || location == 3) { /* some code */ }
```

but because you are using numbers in a specific range, it's shorter to use

```
if (location > 0 && location < 4) { /* some code */ }
```

you can also write a function to compare multiple values:

```
bool Compare(object variable, params object[] values) {
    foreach (object value in values) if (!(variable == value)) return false;
    return true;
}
```